# How to determine input datatype?

Tags: input

I want to accept two inputs. If both the inputs are integer then add them. If any or both the inputs are string then concatenate them. I want to know the code to determine whether the input is integer or string?
Thanks for reading...

Comment: for which technology you are trying? and what have you tried so far?

Comment: if for java, try to parse to integer and if exception is caught then it's string else integer

Comment: Check out my answer for java, You can use method overloading for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use method overloading for this,
Check out Java code given below

```
public class MethodExample
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
         int a,b;
         String string1,string2;
         //accept values for all variables...;>>
         System.Out.Println("Addtion is "+sum(a,b));
         System.Out.Println("Contact is "+sum(string1,string2));
    }

    int sum(int a,int b)
    {
        return(a+b);
    }

    String sum(string a,string b)
    {
        return(a+b);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following logic:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter two inputs:");
        string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string s2 = Console.ReadLine();
        double num;
        int s3;
        string s4;

        bool isNum1 = double.TryParse(s1, out num);
        bool isNum2 = double.TryParse(s2, out num);
        if( isNum1==true && isNum2==true) 
        {
            s3 = Convert.ToInt32(s1) + Convert.ToInt32(s2);
            Console.WriteLine("Output = {0}", s3);
        }
        else
        {
            s4 = s1 + s2;
            Console.WriteLine("Output = {0}",s4);
        }
```